# Failed to run git clone when using psexec

Tags: git, git-clone, psexec

I'm trying to run git clone from a remote machine using psexec.
When I run it from a local machine it works OK.

```
git clone -b develop --single-branch http://server:8080/git/root/AAA.git C:\GIT_Repository\AAA
```

But when running the same with psexec it seems it's skip the downloading of the files and most of the file are size 1kb (when I run git pull I get everything is up to date)

I run this:

```
c:\PsTools\2.44\psexec.exe \\SERVER -u plm\user -p *** git clone -b develop --single-branch http://server:8080/git/root/AAA.git C:\GIT_Repository\AAA
```

This is the output with verbose

```
Cloning into 'C:\GIT_Repository\AAA'...
POST git-upload-pack (163 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 17, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (18410/18410)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (7842/7842)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (246952/246952)
remote: Total 18410 (delta 9705), reused 18355 (delta 9683)
Receiving objects: 100% (18410/18410), 59.08 MiB | 33.83 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9705/9705), done.
Checking out files: 100% (1383/1383), done.
git exited on server with error code 0.
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved after I installed latest version of GIT :-)